# Attaching a delegate to an object in an Array

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have created a custom UIView, and attached a delegate to it - **it all works beautifully!**

However, 60 of these UIViews are created in an array, in a loop. 
And when I try to attach the delegate to one of these beauties, I get this Analyze warning: **Property 'delegate' not found on object of type '__strong id'**

Hopefully this is some simple syntax issue?

This works great:

```
myUIView *aSimpleTest = [[myUIView alloc] init…];
aSimpleTest.delegate = self;   //nice!
...
```

This doesn't:

```
for (i=0; i<60; i++){
    [arrayOfItems addObject:[[myUIView alloc] init…];
    [arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:i].delegate = self;//error, as above
    ...
}
```

Would appreciate some help. (Hopefully I don't have to spend another day learning something new!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i=0; i<60; i++){
    myUIView *view = [[myUIView alloc] init…];
    view.delegate = self;
    [arrayOfItems addObject:view];
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**:
You get the error because `[arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:i]` returns `id` that doesn't have `delegate` property. You also could do the following:

```
myUIView *view = (myUIView*)[arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:i];
view.delegate = self;
```

or:

```
[[arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:i] setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Your first solution worked and so did your last one. Thanks very much for your help troolee! :)

Answer (score 1):

in your loop just do:

```
myUIView *tempView = (myUIView*)[arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:i];
tempView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: troolee's suggestion worked great, but thanks anyway rooster117.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cast:

```
((MyUIView*)[arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:i]).delegate = self;
```

(One thing to note, as an aside: always start your class names with a capital letter.)